# How to move Windows, Program Files and etc folders from D to C?

Tags: windows-7, windows, installation, path, drive-letter

I have a machine, which has `Windows`, `Program Files`, `User` folders located on drive `D`. Is it possible to move everything to drive letter `C` without reinstal?

Comment: It might be, but I got the feeling that this is an XY question. Why do you want to move it? WHich problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to change the Drive location of Windows, then you are best to back up all your documents and reinstall Windows.

There are a huge number of registry entries which tie the system together. There would not be any practical way just to "move" Windows to another Drive entirely.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you want. You want to change the drive letters...

Open ***Disk Managment***, right click on a partition.

[image]

Select ***Change Drive Letter and Paths...*** option.

[image]

And click on the ***Change...*** button, and change the drive letter.

[image]